# How can I get row values and not just column names from sqlsrv_fetch_array() in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

This is my PHP code,

I want to display the data, but `$row2[$i]` only contains the `4` column names in the table. If I try to display anything beyond index `3`, I get the following error:

> Warning: Undefined array key 4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\database.php

I'd like to display the `1000` table values below, but they don't seem to be stored in the `$row2[]` array. What do I need to add in order to display all values from the query?

Thanks,

```
    /*Test SQL command*/
    $tsql2 = "SELECT TOP (1000) [TABLE_CATALOG]
      ,[TABLE_SCHEMA]
      ,[TABLE_NAME]
      ,[TABLE_TYPE]
    FROM [History].[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES]";
  
    $stmt2 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql2);  
    if( $stmt2 === false )  
    {  
        echo "Error in executing query.</br>";  
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
    }  
    
    /* Retrieve and display the results of the query. */  
    $row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt2); 
    
    for ($i = 1; $i < 4 ; $i++) {   
        echo "Query Results: ".$row2[$i]."\t";  
    }
    /* Free statement and connection resources. */  
    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt2);
```

Comment: Two issues with your code: 1)The documentation explains that `Based on the value of the $fetchType parameter, the returned array can be a numerically indexed array, an associative array, or both. By default, an array with both numeric and associative keys is returned.`. The returned array is, of course, 0-based, so array key 4 is `undefined ` and you need a different `for` loop: `for ($i = 0; $i <= 3 ; $i++) {`.  2) You need to fetch all thre rows from the returned statement.

Answer (score 0):

sqlsrv_fetch_array will only fetch one row at a time, so you need a loop to get all rows

As described in the documentation see https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt2, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {
    for ($i = 1; $i < 4 ; $i++) {   
        echo "Query Results: ".$row2[$i]."\t";  
    }
}
```